# When I use CSS3 scale to zoom an image, the visible area is smaller

Tags: css

When I use CSS3 scale to zoom animage, the image's size is bigger, but I can't see the whole image. Even though there is a scrollbar, I can see only a part of the image.

Click this link to see a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wwebS/1/).

```
var scale = 1;
$('img').on('click',function(){
    var new_scale = 2 * scale;
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + new_scale +')');
    scale = new_scale;
});
```

I'd like to know how can I see the whole image after a CSS3 scale.

Comment: Don't use vendor prefixes; jQuery will insert them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS `transform` property only affects the rendered content of the element.

If you want the element's layout to occupy more space, you'll need to adjust its width and height explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

While you scale change the padding left and top of the image appropriately...

Example

```
img
{
 padding-left: 17%;
padding-top: 19%;
}
```